# ProtobufJS repeated bytes field not encoding Uint8Array properly

Tags: javascript, protobuf.js, protobufjs

I have a protobuf message defined as:

```
message examplemessage
{
    string field1 = 1;
    string field2 = 2;
    repeated bytes field3 = 3;
}
```

I load my protobuf with:

```
protobuf.load(path).then(root => {
    // global for example
    examplemessage = root.lookupType("test.examplemessage");
    resolve(); 
});
```

I create a protobuf message object with

```
let createdMessage = examplemessage.create({
    field1: "test1",
    field2: "test2",
    field3: new Uint8Array([0,0,0,33])
});
```

I then encode it

```
let encoded = examplemessage.encode(createdMessage).finish();
```

I then decode and expect

```
{
    field1: "test1",
    field2: "test2",
    field3: Uint8Array(4) [0, 0, 0, 33]
}
```

Instead I see

```
{
    field1: "test1",
    field2: "test2",
    [Uint8Array(0), Uint8Array(0), Uint8Array(0), Uint8Array(0)]
}
```

I then changed my protobuf loading to JSON

```
const root = protobuf.Root.fromJSON(json);
```

This works as expected with no other changes.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Thanks

Protoubuf Version: 6.8.6

Browser: Chrome

JSFiddle example with working JSON loading: https://jsfiddle.net/740snmu6/12/

Answer (score 0):

`repeated bytes` means a `Array` of ***bytes*** (as you might already know, the corresponding type of ***bytes*** is `Uint8Array` or `Array` in JavaScript), so to make it work, you should create the message in this way:

```js
{
    field1: "test1",
    field2: "test2",
    field3: [new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 33]), new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 33]), new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 33])]
}
```